# PHP responding before image is created

Tags: php, ajax

Users can upload an image one at a time which is sent to the server via AJAX. On the php side I'm creating the new image using imagepng. After the image is created, the AJAX post function calls it's callback to then get all images and display them. The problem is, the get request is being executed before the image is being created. It seems like php is responding before it has even created the image.

The question is, does php execute imagepng and immediately respond or does it wait until the new file is created?

submitCallback function

```
submitCallback: function() {
        Modal.submitUpdate(this.getAttribute('data-id'), function() {

            Modal.destroy(); // Hide and reset the modal
            getImages(); // Get all images to display
        });
    },
```

submitUpdate function

```
submitUpdate: function(id, callback) {

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                    console.log(this.responseText);
                    // If a response was provided, decode json             

                    callback();
                }
            };
            request.open("POST", url);
            request.send(formData);
        }
    }
```

On the php side it's just `imagepng($this->image, $filePath);`

The callback seems fine... I can visually see the file appearing seconds after the server is responding. I tried adding a delay until the file exists with:

```
// Sleep until the file has been created
while(!file_exists($filePath)) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

But that doesn't seem to stop the server from responding before the file is created.

Comment: how about showing some code?

Comment: Can you show your code ? The problem may be with the way you are implementing callback functions or your backend logic.

Comment: Added js function and callback.